# Fast moving average computation with Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, django-postgresql

We run Postgres 9.6.5 and Django 2.0. We have a `Model` with fields `created_at` and `value`. We need to calculate a 90-day moving average for a certain `date_range`. This is how we do this:

```
output = []

for i in range(len(date_range)):
    output.append(
        Model.objects.filter(
            created_at__date__range=(date_range[i]-timezone.timedelta(days=90), date_range[i]),
        ).aggregate(Avg('value'))['value__avg'].days
    )
```

This uses `Avg` aggregate function, so it's reasonably fast, however we need one query for every date in `date_range`. For longer ranges this means a lot of queries.

[Postgres can do this in a single query](https://www.compose.com/articles/metrics-maven-calculating-a-moving-average-in-postgresql/). My question is - can we somehow do this in a single query using Django ORM?

*(I know that I can execute raw SQL with Django ORM, but I wanted to avoid this if possible, which is why I'm asking.)*

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a single entry per date you can use Django 2.0's new window expressions to calculate a 90-period moving average in a single query:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, F, RowRange, Window

items = Model.objects.annotate(
    avg=Window(
        expression=Avg('value'), 
        order_by=F('created_at').asc(), 
        frame=RowRange(start=-90,end=0)
    )
)
```

See also [ValueRange](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.Window) if you would like to frame by specific field values instead, which might come in handy if you have multiple rows for each given day for example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of aggregation, you could use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet). Consider this as I start for testing, I'm not completely sure about the code below. See also the docs about [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters) objects

```
    Model.objects.annotate(
        value_avg=Avg(
            'value',
            filter=Q(
                created_at__date__range=(
                    F('created_at__date')-timezone.timedelta(days=90),
                    F('created_at__date')
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

`your_date_field` depends what you

Comment: Thanks. I can't see the logic in your solution. I need a moving average for every day in the date range. Why would it help if I had it for a model instance?

Comment: I thought each date was associated with your model. But if it's independent, my approach doesn't work indeed.

Comment: It is, but it's one to many relation. One date can have multiple model instances. Sorry about not clarifying that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another try. This is more performant in that it only uses one query, but fetches all required Model-instances from the DB to do the logic in python instead of the DB level. Still not optimal, but hopefully it does the right thing this time ;) You have to compare if it really gives a performance improvement in your case.

```
import numpy as np
instances =  Model.objects.filter(
        created_at__gte=min(date_range)-timezone.timedelta(days=90),
        created_at__lte=max(date_range)
    ).values('created_at', 'value')

instances = list(instances)  # evaluate QuerySet and hit DB only once

output = []
for i in range(len(date_range)):    
    output.append(
        np.mean(np.array([inst.value for inst in instances if \
            inst.created_at >= date_range[i]-timezone.timedelta(days=90) and \
            inst.created_at <  date_range[i]
        ]))
    )
```